# Check For legal Value exist in Master table

Tags: sql, t-sql

Respected Techie, may someone please help me how to achieve the below scenario.

I have two tables with a highly denormalized nature, `Master` and `child table`.

For a given specific line there is some valid footnote, and I need to check in `child table` whether a child table contain only those footnote for the line which is present in `Master`. If not that record need to be in output

Table

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
Footnote VARCHAR (50),
Line VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MASTER

SELECT 'O031',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'CAMSHAFT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'DSHBRDCOVR' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O040',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V133',  'DSHBRDCOVR' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V133',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E014',  'CAMSHAFT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E014',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O062',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O194',  'EXHAUSTMUF'




DECLARE @ChildTable TABLE
(   
line    VARCHAR (50),
footnote_list VARCHAR (50)

)
INSERT @ChildTable

select 'EXHAUSTMUF',    'O031, V049' UNION ALL
select 'EXHAUSTMUF' ,'O040, V133' UNION ALL
select 'EXHAUSTMUF',    'E014, O062, O194' UNION ALL
select 'DSHBRDCOVR',    'USP2,LTS9' UNION ALL
select 'DSHBRDCOVR',    'V049'
```

Output

```
DSHBRDCOVR  USP2,LTS9
```

be in output, since line DSHBRDCOVR does not have footnote either USP2 or LTS9.

Thanks

Comment: i am not sure whether it is possible or not.kindly help if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First add one function:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString](     @string NVARCHAR(MAX),     @delimiter CHAR(1),   @keylist nvarchar(50)) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX),keyName nvarchar(50)) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata,keyName)  
        VALUES(ltrim(rtrim( SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start))),@keylist) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

Then

```
DECLARE @MASTER TABLE
(
Footnote VARCHAR (50),
Line VARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT @MASTER

SELECT 'O031',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'CAMSHAFT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'DSHBRDCOVR' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V049',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O040',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V133',  'DSHBRDCOVR' UNION ALL
SELECT 'V133',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E014',  'CAMSHAFT' UNION ALL
SELECT 'E014',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O062',  'EXHAUSTMUF' UNION ALL
SELECT 'O194',  'EXHAUSTMUF'




DECLARE @ChildTable TABLE
(   
line    VARCHAR (50),
footnote_list VARCHAR (50)

)
--storing splitted values
DECLARE @SplittedTable TABLE
(   
splitted    VARCHAR (50),
keys VARCHAR (50)

)

INSERT @ChildTable

select 'EXHAUSTMUF',    'O031, V049' UNION ALL
select 'EXHAUSTMUF' ,'O040, V133' UNION ALL
select 'EXHAUSTMUF',    'E014, O062, O194' UNION ALL
select 'DSHBRDCOVR',    'USP2,LTS9' UNION ALL
select 'DSHBRDCOVR',    'V049' 

--getting max rows
declare @maxRows int =(SELECT count(*) FROM @childtable)

--loop over each rows
WHILE(@maxRows!=0)
BEGIN
DECLARE @footNotList nvarchar(max)=( SELECT abc.footnote_list FROM (SELECT ct.footnote_list, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ct.footnote_list DESC) AS RowNumber
        FROM @ChildTable AS ct
)  abc WHERE abc.RowNumber=@maxRows )
--inserting into splitted table
INSERT INTO @SplittedTable
SELECT * FROM dbo.fnSplitString(@footNotList,',',@footNotList) 
set @maxRows=@maxRows-1;
END

--selecting by keys and finding them into master
SELECT * FROM @ChildTable ct WHERE ct.footnote_list IN (
SELECT DISTINCT st.keys FROM @SplittedTable AS st WHERE st.splitted  NOT IN (SELECT Footnote FROM @MASTER m ))
```

Output:

[image]

Let me know if there is any problem. I tested it

Comment: will it be possible to boost the performance, it took more than 3 hour and still continue executing.
my table contains million of record.. thanks

Comment: Don't think so. may be you can improve by debugging.